# RPS Showing Up As Draw Every time

Tags: ruby

Earlier I asked about adding points to a RPS game I created, that problem is fixed, but now I have a new problem.. Every time the user rolls for their item (rock, paper, or scissors) it's a draw. I've tried adding a percentage to the array 33.5% for two and 33% for one which adds to 100 and it still comes up as a draw every time.

```
def welcome
  puts "Welcome to Rock, Paper, Scissors. To begin press 'S'. 
  To learn how to play press 'I'. To quit the game press 'Q'"
  input = gets.chomp
    if input =~ /s/i
      start_game
    elsif input =~ /i/i
      instructions
    else
      exit
    end
 end

def start_game
  start_points_P1 = 0
  start_points_P2 = 0
  choice = ['Rock', 'Paper', 'Scissors']
  choice2 = ['Rock', 'Paper', 'Scissors']
  player1 = choice.sample
  player2 = choice2.sample
  puts "Press 'R' to roll for Player 1"
  input = gets.chomp!
  puts "Player 1 has recieved #{player1}"
  puts "Press 'E' to roll for Player 2!"
  input = gets.chomp!
  puts "Player 2 has recieved #{player2}"
    if player1 == player2
      puts "Draw!"
      start_game
    elsif player1 == 'Paper' && player2 == 'Scissors'
      start_points_P2 += 10
      puts "Player 2 has won with #{player2}. You now have #{start_points_P2} points and opponent has #{start_points_P1} points"
    elsif player1 == 'Scissors' && player2 == 'Paper'
      start_points_P1 += 10
      puts "Player 1 has won with #{player1}. You know have #{start_points_P1} points and opponent has #{start_points_P2} points"
    elsif player1 == 'Rock' && player2 == 'Paper'
      start_points_P2 += 10
      puts "Player 2 has won with #{player2}. You now have #{start_points_P2} points and opponent has #{start_points_P1} points"
    elsif player1 == 'Paper' && player2 == 'Rock'
      start_points_P1 += 10
      puts "Player 1 has won with #{player1}. You know have #{start_points_P1} points and opponent has #{start_points_P2} points"
    elsif player1 == 'Scissors' && player2 == 'Rock'
      start_points_P2 += 10
      puts "Player 2 has won with #{player2}. You now have #{start_points_P2} points and opponent has #{start_points_P1} points"
    elsif player1 == 'Rock' && player2 == 'Scissors'
      start_points_P1 += 10
      puts "Player 1 has won with #{player1}. You know have #{start_points_P1} points and opponent has #{start_points_P2} points"
    end
end
welcome
```

Am I missing something here, why does it keep showing up as a draw if I have set the players into separate arrays and only called `.sample` once?

Comment: Having two arrays `choice` and `choice2` does not have any meaning. `win` is not used anywhere.

Comment: Cannot be reproduced.

Comment: Win will be used in just not using it yet, I'm going to use it as the final score of the game.

Comment: removed it.. So back to the question..

Comment: Can anybody help me with this..?

Comment: Have you ever read my second comment?

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read "[ask]". Your code won't run as is: You never call `start_game`, and `welcome` is undefined.